# Firebase Verification Email Template not updating

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I had issues with Firebase verification emails going to the spam folder and I decided to change the email template like this:

**Sender name**: from 'noreply' to 'AppName'.
**From**: from 'noreply@...firebaseapp.com' to 'verification@...firebaseapp.com'

But I still get the old noreply emails. Any ideas why?

I send the email like this (Swift):

```
Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: emailAddress, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings)
```

Answer (score 0):

please check & let me know what you get.

```
        let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
        actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "firebase url") // firebase url looks like this firebase-productid.firebaseapp.com & firebase product id will find in googleservices-info.plist
        actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
        actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail:email, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings) { error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: I have all these in place, I don't think it is a client config issue.

Comment: can you tell me what's error you get using the error block.